# Proxy Selenium Python Firefox. Working example?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, selenium-firefoxdriver

This proxy startup code does not work, you can substitute any digits in the proxy, the result is launch without a proxy. What am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

myProxy = "46.151.150.11:9999"

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
    })


driver = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy)
driver.get("https://2ip.ua/ru/")
```